# How to create JSON or Array of Objects From Three JS Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to load into/generate a JSON object or an Array of Objects like below

```
var players = [
        {"name":"John", "startPoint":"3", "maxPoint":"80"}, 
        {"name":"Anna", "startPoint":"6", "maxPoint":"28"}, 
        {"name":"Peter", "startPoint":"6", "maxPoint":"80"},
        {"name":"Zack", "startPoint":"2", "maxPoint":"65"}, 
        {"name":"Andy", "startPoint":"4", "maxPoint":"80"}, 
        {"name":"Mick", "startPoint":"0", "maxPoint":"65"}, 
        {"name":"Robin", "startPoint":"2", "maxPoint":"80"}, 
        {"name":"Ed", "startPoint":"5", "maxPoint":"28"}, 
        {"name":"Chris", "startPoint":"1", "maxPoint":"65"}, 
        {"name":"Lee", "startPoint":"3", "maxPoint":"80"}, 
        {"name":"Baron", "startPoint":"6", "maxPoint":"65"}, 
        {"name":"Sam", "startPoint":"1", "maxPoint":"80"}   
];
```

from three JavaScript Array Object as:

```
var members = ["John","Anna","Peter","Zack","Andy","Mick","Robin","Ed","Chris","Lee","Baron" ,"Sam" ]
var startPoint = [3, 6, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 1];
var maxPoint =[80, 28, 80, 65, 80, 65, 80, 80, 65, 80, 65, 80];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < members.length; ++i) {
    result.push({name: members[i], startPoint: startPoint[i], maxPoint: maxPoint[i]});
}
return JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice but the console.log(result) is not returning any thinsg. Can you please take a look at this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/pxvxq37x/1/

Comment: Replace return JSON.stringify(result);
console.log(result); with console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: just one more question?

Comment: how come it is not alerting the `alert(result[0].name );` at this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/pxvxq37x/3/

Comment: because of the return statement: the alert is unreachable

Comment: so ? if we disable the `.stringify()` how the JSON objext will be created?

Comment: If you need the JSON string, assign it to a variable instead of returning it

Comment: you can also move the alert statement before the return statement